# Adding "de" to es-ES CultureInfo DateTime C#

Tags: c#, datetime, cultureinfo

Probably dumb question, but I haven't worked with Culture a whole bunch before. The assets for the date need to be:

MMMM dd "de" yyyy  (w/o quotes on the "de").

junio 1 de 2015

What I have now:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("es-ES", false);
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd REPLACE yyyy", ci).Replace("REPLACE", "de");
```

I want to know if there's a "more programatically correct" way of doing this that I do not know about rather than doing the `string.Replace`

Comment: I think you just need to escape the d, like \d (e.g. ToString("MMMM dd \de yyyy", ci)) see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just quote the literal part with single quotes, double-quotes, or escape each character with a backslash:

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd 'de' yyyy", ci);
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd \"de\" yyyy", ci);
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MMMM dd \d\e yyyy", ci);
```

Note that in the second option we need to escape the `"` within the string literal, and in the third option I'm using a verbatim string literal to avoid escaping the backslashes. Using single quotes is simplest :)

Read [custom date and time format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4) for more details in general about what you can do.

Comment: didn't know you could do this - appreicate it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand clearly, you can escape your `de` part with single quote like;

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd 'de' yyyy", ci);
```

or with double quote;

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd \"de\" yyyy", ci);
```

or with escape character as a [verbatim string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx);

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MMMM dd \d\e yyyy", ci);
```

I almost prefer using single quote because `"` and `\` might be confusing.

More information at;

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the characters with a backslash:

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MMMM dd \d\e yyyy", ci)
```

See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4).

Note the `@`, which prevents the backslash from being parsed as a string literal escape.